# php session and while-loop: undefined index

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, session-variables

I am trying to pass a variable through a session. I use a while loop to run through a database, which works perfectly. If `$username` and `$password` are correct I always get these error notices:

> Notice: Undefined index: GELD in login.php on line
>
> Notice: Undefined index: NIVEAU in login.php on line

Why do I get these error notices and how could I resolve them?

index.html

```
<form id="loginform" method="post" action="login.php">
    <img src="afbeelding/logo.png">
    <label for="username">
        Username
    </label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username"/>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $dbhost = 'sql7.xxx.net';
    $dbuser = 'xxx';
    $dbpass = 'xxx';
    $db = 'xxx';

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];

    $con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($db, $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM Game");

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if($row{'USERNAME'} == $username){
            if($row{'PASSWORD'} == $password){
                $_SESSION['geld'] = $row{'GELD'};
                $_SESSION['niveau'] = $row{'NIVEAU'};
            }
            else{
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: `$row{'GELD'}` => `$row['GELD']` etc. same for `$row{'PASSWORD'}` don't use braces. use brackets

Comment: By using brackets I keep getting the same error message.

Comment: Yeah that's very basic :P But I'm more worried about deprecated mysql.

Comment: *Hold on here cowboy*, you didn't even query yet (where is `$result` here?) and we don't know which MySQL API you're using to connect with, if you even connected.

Comment: I will add it to the code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$row{'GELD'}` is the same as `$row['GELD']` you just don't see it very often. See the note above the example: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-102

Comment: plus we don't know if your column names are uppercase or not. `GELD` and `geld` are two different animals altogether.

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm going to pass on this one. Too many times I've seen questions like these in the past few days where they leave out information they think is irrelevant. Good luck to all on this one.

Comment: `SELECT ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM Game` - there you didn't select `GELD` and `NIVEAU` in your query. problem solved.

Comment: Here we go we have it. You never get `GELD` and `NIVEAU` in your select query, so from where should they come from?! (@Fred-ii-)

Comment: @Rizier123 see what I mean?

Comment: I have added the connection to the database, but it works until it has to put `$row['GELD]` into `$_SESSION['geld']`. And in the database all the column-names are uppercase.

Comment: @Fred-ii- They only thing I don't see is, how you have sooo much patience to handle all of these?! ;)

Comment: oh, thank you very much, It works now.

Comment: Fred -ii- & Rizier123 are right, there's no GELD and NIVEAU in your query.

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks for that reference on the braces. See, even I learned a bit more today ;-) Everyone learns and keeps on learning, no matter how much experience one has.

Comment: And us $row[""] instead of {}. It's weird looking even if it works..

Comment: @Rizier123 *"They only thing I don't see is, how you have sooo much patience to handle all of these?!"* - I still grow "cactus", just less than I used to. Went from 1500 cacti to 300 in a single drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM Game` - there you didn't select the `GELD` and `NIVEAU` columns in your query.
and don't use a deprecated MySQL API.

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

**Passwords**

If you're live with this or intend on going live with plain text password, STOP right there.

For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Also consult the manual on `password_verify()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Sidenote about using `password_hash()` and column length.

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or crypt, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

Comment: PDO all the way ^^ Don't forget about password_verify :P

Comment: @PVL Indeed. Added the `password_verify()` reference. Thanks, *cheers*